# Dynamic rows in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I have 8 images to display in Bootstrap's grid system. Thanks that code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

On the lg, md and sm screen sizes, it is displaying like that ("X" represents image):

XXXX

XXXX

and on the xs screen size, like that:

X

X

X

X

X

X

X

X

I want achieve:

displaying on the lg, md and sm screen sizes:

XXXX

XXXX

and displaying on the xs screen size:

XX

XX

XX

XX

Is anyone who know how do it?

Comment: use class `col-xs-6`

Comment: it's not enought, because it gives me that effect: XX X X XX XX (two images, one image on the right, one image on the left, two images, two images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your `xs` declarations making the image containers span 6 columns at that size:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it gives me that effect:
XX
 X
X
XX
XX
(two images, one image on the right, one image on the left, two images, two images)

Comment: No it doesn't: http://www.bootply.com/STtmq0cYkU If it does then your code is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that my images has different height (+/- 3px). And that is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, we use declarations like sm (small devices) to define which media queries will trigger the column classes for a specific resolution.

`xs` stands for extra small (smartphones/mobiles most)
`sm` stands for small devices (tablets most)
`md` stands for medium devices (some olders non-hd desktops and laptops most)
`lg` stands for large devices (hd screens, retina devices etc)

When you use a class like `col-sm-3` you are telling that from `small devices` and on the element will occupy  3 columns. You can define multiple classes to specify columns for each resolution:

```
col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2
```

**Then it will translate into the following:**

From `xs` resolutions or **below**, the element will occupy 12 columns.

From `sm` resolutions or **above**, the element will occupy 6 columns.

From `md` resolutions or above, the element will occupy 4 columns.

From `lg` resolutions or above, the element will occupy 2 columns.

Don't forget to apply a min-height value to the column so it won't wrap around wrong if the images height have different sizes.

For more detailed information about the grid/column system, check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Comment: Don't forget to apply min-height to the column so it won't wrap around wrong if the images height have different sizes.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that my images has different height (+/- 3px).